# Center an ad on the header

Tags: html, css, center

I'm having some CSS related problems with centering an ad on the header, as you can see if
you scroll down the ad is not in the middle and it looks weird.

Please keep in mind that this site is responsive and works on all screens
and the solution I have right now only works good on mobile devices, but not on PC.

I hope you can help me get it to center.

link to see the problem:  [My Website](http://mywibes.gagthat.com/)

Comment: What is not centered ?

Comment: try with position:absolute `margin: 25px auto 10px;
min-height: 100px;
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
transform: translatex(-50%);
`

Comment: the ad on the header is not centered.

Comment: @Vitorino-Fernandes your code works great only that in smaller devices ans smaller screen size the all header part becomes smaller for some reason, got any ideas?

Comment: you want the header height to be the same then you can give fixed height for `.top`

Comment: @Vitorino-Fernandes I did it and now it looks messed up a bit, can you look?

Comment: add same `height` for the `section` inside `.top` which is adding `shadow`

Comment: @Vitorino-Fernandes I have done what you said and everything now works great! Thanks for the help. how can I give you reputation? (:

Comment: no problem i will add a answer :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this will `center` the ad in the `middle`

```
className{
  margin: 35px auto 10px;
  min-height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translatex(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.your_ad {
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-half of your ad_width;
}
.your_header {position:relative;}
```